# Vuetify vertical align v-select?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm building an application that uses Vuetify. I use **Google Contacts pre-made layout** from Vuetify: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/google-contacts/

I'm been trying to add a **switch languages flag** (using v-select) in the v-app-bar next to the search form. However, I can't make it aligns vertically.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 10):

Use hide-details="auto" in v-select component

Example:

```
<v-select v-model="language" :items="i18n.availableLocales" hide-details="auto" >
</v-select>
```

Comment: Wow, It works and I'm very grateful but I'm a bit confused because the documentation just says "Hides hint and validation errors. When set to auto messages will be rendered only if there’s a message (hint, error message, counter value etc) to display". So I don't get it

Comment: That prop is useful only in the case of form submission for validation purposes imo. Since search boxes usually don't require any form of validation, you can safely use it.